# Optimization of matrix search

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a matrix of 6 columns and 375 rows, the user sets any number.  The task is as follows, find all combinations in which a number is taken from each column (a total of 6 numbers) and their sum should be equal to the number of the user.  I write in python, and have tried many ways, but they are all very slow, I need an hour or less to calculate
UPD. the numbers are all positive
UPD in each row there is an intermediate diesel power and fuel consumption corresponding to this power, so 6 numbers from each column should add up to the number specified by the user and ensure minimum consumption. Fuel consumption is a non-linear characteristic, usually it is like a car, if you are familiar with engines.
n - kilowatts, i - diesel index, Av - diesel consumption grams per kilowatt hour

```
n;i;Av
80;5;330.467
80;6;330.467
85;5;324.551
85;6;324.551
90;5;319.292
90;6;319.292
95;5;314.587
95;6;314.587
100;1;301.271
100;2;301.271
100;5;310.352
100;6;310.352
105;1;296.857
105;2;296.857
105;5;306.52
105;6;306.52
110;1;292.844
110;2;292.844
110;5;303.037
110;6;303.037
115;1;289.18
115;2;289.18
115;5;299.857
115;6;299.857
120;1;285.821
120;2;285.821
120;5;296.942
120;6;296.942
125;1;282.731
125;2;282.731
125;5;294.26
125;6;294.26
130;1;279.879
130;2;279.879
130;3;326.651
130;4;326.651
130;5;291.784
130;6;291.784
135;1;277.238
135;2;277.238
135;3;322.929
135;4;322.929
135;5;289.491
135;6;289.491
140;1;274.785
140;2;274.785
140;3;319.472
140;4;319.472
140;5;287.363
140;6;287.363
145;1;272.502
145;2;272.502
145;3;316.254
145;4;316.254
145;5;285.381
145;6;285.381
150;1;270.371
150;2;270.371
150;3;313.25
150;4;313.25
150;5;283.531
150;6;283.531
155;1;268.378
155;2;268.378
155;3;310.44
155;4;310.44
155;5;281.801
155;6;281.801
160;1;266.509
160;2;266.509
160;3;307.806
160;4;307.806
160;5;280.179
160;6;280.179
165;1;264.753
165;2;264.753
165;3;305.331
165;4;305.331
165;5;278.655
165;6;278.655
170;1;263.101
170;2;263.101
170;3;303.002
170;4;303.002
170;5;277.221
170;6;277.221
175;1;261.543
175;2;261.543
175;3;300.806
175;4;300.806
175;5;275.868
175;6;275.868
180;1;260.071
180;2;260.071
180;3;298.732
180;4;298.732
180;5;274.591
180;6;274.591
185;1;258.68
185;2;258.68
185;3;296.77
185;4;296.77
185;5;273.383
185;6;273.383
190;1;257.361
190;2;257.361
190;3;294.912
190;4;294.912
190;5;272.238
190;6;272.238
195;1;256.11
195;2;256.11
195;3;293.148
195;4;293.148
195;5;271.153
195;6;271.153
200;1;254.921
200;2;254.921
200;3;291.473
200;4;291.473
200;5;270.121
200;6;270.121
205;1;253.791
205;2;253.791
205;3;289.88
205;4;289.88
205;5;269.14
205;6;269.14
210;1;252.714
210;2;252.714
210;3;288.362
210;4;288.362
210;5;268.205
210;6;268.205
215;1;251.688
215;2;251.688
215;3;286.915
215;4;286.915
215;5;267.314
215;6;267.314
220;1;250.708
220;2;250.708
220;3;285.534
220;4;285.534
220;5;266.464
220;6;266.464
225;1;249.772
225;2;249.772
225;3;284.214
225;4;284.214
225;5;265.651
225;6;265.651
230;1;248.876
230;2;248.876
230;3;282.952
230;4;282.952
230;5;264.874
230;6;264.874
235;1;248.018
235;2;248.018
235;3;281.743
235;4;281.743
235;5;264.129
235;6;264.129
240;1;247.197
240;2;247.197
240;3;280.585
240;4;280.585
240;5;263.416
240;6;263.416
245;1;246.408
245;2;246.408
245;3;279.474
245;4;279.474
245;5;262.732
245;6;262.732
250;1;245.652
250;2;245.652
250;3;278.407
250;4;278.407
250;5;262.075
250;6;262.075
255;1;244.925
255;2;244.925
255;3;277.383
255;4;277.383
255;5;261.444
255;6;261.444
260;1;244.225
260;2;244.225
260;3;276.397
260;4;276.397
260;5;260.837
260;6;260.837
265;1;243.553
265;2;243.553
265;3;275.449
265;4;275.449
265;5;260.253
265;6;260.253
270;1;242.905
270;2;242.905
270;3;274.536
270;4;274.536
270;5;259.691
270;6;259.691
275;1;242.281
275;2;242.281
275;3;273.656
275;4;273.656
275;5;259.149
275;6;259.149
280;1;241.679
280;2;241.679
280;3;272.808
280;4;272.808
280;5;258.627
280;6;258.627
285;1;241.098
285;2;241.098
285;3;271.989
285;4;271.989
285;5;258.122
285;6;258.122
290;1;240.537
290;2;240.537
290;3;271.198
290;4;271.198
290;5;257.636
290;6;257.636
295;1;239.995
295;2;239.995
295;3;270.435
295;4;270.435
295;5;257.165
295;6;257.165
300;1;239.472
300;2;239.472
300;3;269.697
300;4;269.697
300;5;256.711
300;6;256.711
305;1;238.965
305;2;238.965
305;3;268.983
305;4;268.983
305;5;256.271
305;6;256.271
310;1;238.475
310;2;238.475
310;3;268.292
310;4;268.292
310;5;255.846
310;6;255.846
315;1;238
315;2;238
315;3;267.623
315;4;267.623
315;5;255.43
315;6;255.43
320;1;237.54
320;2;237.54
320;3;266.975
320;4;266.975
325;1;237.095
325;2;237.095
325;3;266.346
325;4;266.346
330;1;236.663
330;2;236.663
330;3;265.737
330;4;265.737
335;1;236.243
335;2;236.243
335;3;265.146
335;4;265.146
340;1;235.836
340;2;235.836
340;3;264.573
340;4;264.573
345;1;235.441
345;2;235.441
345;3;264.016
345;4;264.016
350;1;235.057
350;2;235.057
350;3;263.475
350;4;263.475
355;1;234.684
355;2;234.684
355;3;262.949
355;4;262.949
360;1;234.322
360;2;234.322
360;3;262.438
360;4;262.438
365;1;233.969
365;2;233.969
365;3;261.941
365;4;261.941
370;1;233.626
370;2;233.626
370;3;261.457
370;4;261.457
375;1;233.292
375;2;233.292
375;3;260.986
375;4;260.986
380;1;232.966
380;2;232.966
380;3;260.527
380;4;260.527
385;1;232.65
385;2;232.65
385;3;260.081
385;4;260.081
390;1;232.341
390;2;232.341
390;3;259.646
390;4;259.646
395;1;232.04
395;2;232.04
395;3;259.222
395;4;259.222
400;1;231.747
400;2;231.747
400;3;258.808
400;4;258.808
405;3;258.405
405;4;258.405
410;3;258.012
410;4;258.012
415;3;257.628
415;4;257.628
420;3;257.253
420;4;257.253
425;3;256.887
425;4;256.887
430;3;256.529
430;4;256.529
435;3;256.18
435;4;256.18
440;3;255.839
440;4;255.839
445;3;255.505
445;4;255.505
450;3;255.179
450;4;255.179
455;3;254.86
455;4;254.86
460;3;254.548
460;4;254.548
465;3;254.242
465;4;254.242
470;3;253.943
470;4;253.943
475;3;253.651
475;4;253.651
480;3;253.364
480;4;253.364
485;3;253.083
485;4;253.083
490;3;252.809
490;4;252.809
495;3;252.539
495;4;252.539
500;3;252.275
500;4;252.275
505;3;252.016
505;4;252.016
510;3;251.763
510;4;251.763
515;3;251.514
515;4;251.514
520;3;251.27
520;4;251.27
```

UPD. They helped me in the comments, I tried this code, it works, but it needs improvement for me, because I can't find the functions for my expenses

```
import pulp
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


list_df = []
df = pd.read_csv('ruchki.csv', sep=';')

def quadratic_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x**2 + b * x + c

for i in range(1, 7):
    condition = df['i'] == i
    df1 = df[condition]
    x = df1['n'].values
    y = df1['Av'].values
    params_quadratic, covariance_quadratic = curve_fit(quadratic_func, x, y)
    a, b, c = params_quadratic
    list_df.append([a, b, c])

engine_W = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'power_min': [100, 100, 130, 130, 80, 80],
        'power_max': [400, 400, 520, 520, 315, 315],
    },
    index=pd.RangeIndex(name='engine', start=0, stop=6),
)

output_W = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.linspace(
        start=engine_W['power_min'],
        stop=engine_W['power_max'],
        num=50,
    ),
    columns=engine_W.index,
)

# quadratic diesel fuel model, L/J
fuel_models = [
    Polynomial((list_df[0][2], list_df[0][1], list_df[0][0])),
    Polynomial((list_df[1][2], list_df[1][1], list_df[1][0])),
    Polynomial((list_df[2][2], list_df[2][1], list_df[2][0])),
    Polynomial((list_df[3][2], list_df[3][1], list_df[3][0])),
    Polynomial((list_df[4][2], list_df[4][1], list_df[4][0])),
    Polynomial((list_df[5][2], list_df[5][1], list_df[5][0])),

]
num_points = 50
num_engines = len(engine_W)

input_L_J = np.zeros((num_points, num_engines))

for engine, model in enumerate(fuel_models):
    input_L_J[:, engine] = model(output_W.loc[:, engine])

print(input_L_J)

target_W = 1000
assignments = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
    name='asn', cat=pulp.LpBinary,
    indices=(range(num_engines), range(num_points)),

)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='diesel_generation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.objective = pulp.LpAffineExpression()
total_output = pulp.LpAffineExpression()

for engine, engine_group in enumerate(assignments):
    prob.addConstraint(name=f'engine_excl_{engine}', constraint=pulp.lpSum(engine_group) <= 1)
    prob.objective += pulp.lpDot(engine_group, input_L_J[:, engine])

    total_output += pulp.lpDot(engine_group, output_W.loc[:, engine])

prob.addConstraint(name='total_power', constraint=total_output == target_W)

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

cons_idx = [
    next((i for i, var in enumerate(engine_group) if var.value() > 0.5), None)
    for engine_group in assignments
]
for engine, idx in enumerate(cons_idx):
    if idx is not None:
        print(
            'Engine', engine, 'active at', output_W.loc[idx, engine], 'kW, '
            f'consuming {input_L_J[idx, engine]:.1f}'

        )
```

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: @João Areias, No, but if you direct me, I'll get acquainted

Comment: Think of it as a recursion of something like this `find_combinations(matrix, col_indx, remaining)`  and what are the implications of choosing a number from a column

Comment: Actually, coming to think about it, it's not even about dynamic programming, I believe a simple recursion would do the trick

Comment: Is the matrix size fixed? Is it always 6 by 375, because if it is, you can actually just use for loops

Comment: Do you check the same matrix repeatedly for diffferent numbers?

Comment: Are the matrix elements positive, or not necessarily? Integers, or not necessarily?

Comment: The numbers are all positive, I can describe the work in more detail if it helps you

Comment: Please edit that into your question

Comment: This is for choosing the loading of diesels, I have 6 diesels, they have a load range in which they can work, respectively, diesels are columns, and their power range in increments of 5 kW is rows, I plan to save the results to the cloud and just use them

Comment: The approach needs re-thinking. Probably shouldn't have the list be in load increments. Please show the minimum and maximum capacity for each diesel in your question.

Comment: Yes, but each intermediate power has a specific fuel consumption, I strive to minimize it, so intermediate values are important to me

Comment: The point is, if these are "increments of 5 kW", you don't need to (and shouldn't) store them, since they are determined implicitly, and this gives opportunity for much more efficiency in the algorithm. This kind of information is essential to the question, and should be in there.

Comment: Well, the maximum and minimum diesel power values are 100 and 500 kW, the load value is 300 kW, how will I choose diesels that provide this power with minimal fuel consumption

Comment: How is the fuel consumption determined? Is there a table, or is it a linear coefficient? Please **edit your question** to include all of these details.

Comment: Notice that your consumption (when converted to grams per hour) is a perfectly linear function. Later tonight I will show how this simplifies your problem.

Comment: Thank you, you kind man. I am very grateful to you for your support. I can show you what kind of output I expect from the program. Conditionally, we have a power of 600 kW, conditionally, this power with a minimum consumption can be provided by diesels 1, 2 out of all 6. In the answer, it is planned to output diesel indexes, their power as in the file and the consumption of the format is also as in the file, I need it to control diesels and solar panels. Here is an example output
[i,n, Av]
[1, 235, 248.018]
[2, 365, 233.969]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First cut: assignment

If we assume that the fuel consumption is tabular and *can't be represented by a continuous function*, then this is a simple assignment problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

engine_W = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'power_min': [100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300],
        'power_max': [300, 325, 350, 400, 450, 500],
    },
    index=pd.RangeIndex(name='engine', start=0, stop=6),
)*1e3

output_W = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.linspace(
        start=engine_W['power_min'],
        stop=engine_W['power_max'],
        num=41,
    ),
    columns=engine_W.index,
)

# quadratic diesel fuel model, L/J
quadfuel = Polynomial((6.722e-8, 3.380e-8, 1.166e-8))
output_frac = output_W / engine_W['power_max']
input_L_J = quadfuel(output_frac)
input_L_s = input_L_J * engine_W['power_max']

target_W = 1000e3
assignments = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
    name='asn', cat=pulp.LpBinary,
    indices=(engine_W.index, input_L_s.index),
)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='diesel_generation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.objective = pulp.LpAffineExpression()
total_output = pulp.LpAffineExpression()

for engine, engine_group in enumerate(assignments):
    prob.addConstraint(name=f'engine_excl_{engine}', constraint=pulp.lpSum(engine_group) <= 1)
    prob.objective += pulp.lpDot(engine_group, input_L_s.loc[:, engine])
    total_output += pulp.lpDot(engine_group, output_W.loc[:, engine])

prob.addConstraint(name='total_power', constraint=total_output == target_W)

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

cons_idx = [
    next((i for i, var in enumerate(engine_group) if var.value() > 0.5), None)
    for engine_group in assignments
]
for engine, idx in enumerate(cons_idx):
    if idx is not None:
        print(
            'Engine', engine, 'active at', output_W.loc[idx, engine]*1e-3, 'kW, '
            f'consuming {input_L_s.loc[idx, engine]*60*60:.1f} l/h'
        )
```

```
Engine 0 active at 295.0 kW, consuming 120.7 l/h
Engine 1 active at 315.0 kW, consuming 129.8 l/h
Engine 3 active at 390.0 kW, consuming 160.2 l/h
```

Notice that I used a continuous 2-degree model anyway, to produce synthetic data.

### Second cut: assignment and continuous

The much more advisable approach is to produce a continuous model for fuel consumption. This is quite easy because your fuel consumption (when in units of mass per time) is perfectly linear.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def load(filename: str = '77000778.csv') -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        filename, sep=';',
    ).rename(columns={
        'n': 'power_kW',
        'i': 'engine',
        'Av': 'consume_g_kWh',
    })
    df['consume_g_h'] = df['consume_g_kWh'] * df['power_kW']
    return df


def linregress(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    params = pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.RangeIndex(name='engine', start=df['engine'].min(), stop=df['engine'].max()+1),
    )
    grouped = df.groupby('engine')
    params['pmin'] = grouped['power_kW'].min()
    params['pmax'] = grouped['power_kW'].max()

    for engine, group in grouped:
        fit, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(
            a=np.stack((group['power_kW'], np.ones(len(group))), axis=1),
            b=group['consume_g_h'],
            rcond=None,
        )
        params.loc[engine, ['m', 'b']] = fit

    return params


def make_vars(consume_params: pd.DataFrame) -> tuple[
    dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],  # engine assignment
    dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],  # engine usage
]:
    assign = {
        engine:
        pulp.LpVariable(
            name=f'assign_{engine}', cat=pulp.LpBinary,
        )
        for engine in consume_params.index
    }
    power = {
        engine:
        pulp.LpVariable(
            name=f'power_{engine}', cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        )
        for engine in consume_params.index
    }
    return assign, power


def make_objective(
    assign: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
    power: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
    consume_params: pd.DataFrame,
) -> pulp.LpAffineExpression:
    return pulp.lpDot(
        power.values(),
        consume_params['m'],
    ) + pulp.lpDot(
        assign.values(),
        consume_params['b'],
    )


def add_constraints(
    prob: pulp.LpProblem,
    assign: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
    power: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
    consume_params: pd.DataFrame,
    target_power: float,
) -> None:
    prob.addConstraint(
        name='total_power',
        constraint=target_power == pulp.lpSum(power.values()),
    )

    for engine, row in consume_params.iterrows():
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'pmin_{engine}',
            constraint=power[engine] >= row['pmin']*assign[engine],
        )
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'pmax_{engine}',
            constraint=power[engine] <= row['pmax']*assign[engine],
        )


def dump(
    assign: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
    power: dict[int, pulp.LpVariable],
) -> None:
    for engine, asn in assign.items():
        if asn.value() > 0.5:
            p = power[engine].value()
            print(f'Engine {engine} runs at {p:.1f} kW')


def plot(df: pd.DataFrame, consume_params: pd.DataFrame) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, (ax_left, ax_right) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

    ax_left.set_xlabel('Power (kW)')
    ax_left.set_ylabel('Consumption (g/kWh)')
    ax_right.set_xlabel('Power (kW)')
    ax_right.set_ylabel('Consumption (g/h)')

    for engine, group in df.groupby('engine'):
        ax_left.scatter(group['power_kW'], group['consume_g_kWh'], label=f'table ({engine})', s=8)
        ax_right.scatter(group['power_kW'], group['consume_g_h'], label=f'table ({engine})', s=8)

        params = consume_params.loc[engine]
        power = np.linspace(start=params['pmin'], stop=params['pmax'], num=201)
        g_h = params['m']*power + params['b']
        g_kwh = g_h / power

        ax_left.plot(power, g_kwh, label=f'fit ({engine})')
        ax_right.plot(power, g_h, label=f'fit ({engine})')
    ax_left.legend(title='Engine')

    return fig


def main() -> None:
    df = load()
    consume_params = linregress(df)

    assign, power = make_vars(consume_params)
    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='diesel_generation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
    prob.objective = make_objective(assign, power, consume_params)
    add_constraints(prob, assign, power, consume_params, target_power=970.3)

    print(prob)
    prob.solve()
    assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
    dump(assign, power)

    plot(df, consume_params)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
diesel_generation:
MINIMIZE
9269.900724484416*assign_1 + 9269.900724484416*assign_2 + 13066.01881329114*assign_3 + 13066.01881329114*assign_4 + 8046.24272579243*assign_5 + 8046.24272579243*assign_6 + 208.57198202009533*power_1 + 208.57198202009533*power_2 + 226.14324824732228*power_3 + 226.14324824732228*power_4 + 229.88975993269645*power_5 + 229.88975993269645*power_6 + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
total_power: power_1 + power_2 + power_3 + power_4 + power_5 + power_6 = 970.3

pmin_1: - 100 assign_1 + power_1 >= 0

pmax_1: - 400 assign_1 + power_1 <= 0

pmin_2: - 100 assign_2 + power_2 >= 0

pmax_2: - 400 assign_2 + power_2 <= 0

pmin_3: - 130 assign_3 + power_3 >= 0

pmax_3: - 520 assign_3 + power_3 <= 0

pmin_4: - 130 assign_4 + power_4 >= 0

pmax_4: - 520 assign_4 + power_4 <= 0

pmin_5: - 80 assign_5 + power_5 >= 0

pmax_5: - 315 assign_5 + power_5 <= 0

pmin_6: - 80 assign_6 + power_6 >= 0

pmax_6: - 315 assign_6 + power_6 <= 0

VARIABLES
0 <= assign_1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_5 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_6 <= 1 Integer
power_1 free Continuous
power_2 free Continuous
power_3 free Continuous
power_4 free Continuous
power_5 free Continuous
power_6 free Continuous
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                232593.85590738
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               1
Time (CPU seconds):             0.01
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Engine 1 runs at 400.0 kW
Engine 2 runs at 400.0 kW
Engine 5 runs at 170.3 kW
```

[image: fits]

Comment: My data is stored in a csv file, if it can be displayed somewhere, I will be happy to share it with you

Comment: I'm inexperienced, but I ran your code at home, I'm trying to figure it out, I really like your approach

Comment: Yes, you are right, my consumption is in the table, but it can be represented as a continuous function, but these functions are not the same for all diesels

Comment: And my data is stored in grams per kilowatt

Comment: I've updated the data, you know I'm working on your code, I'm close to the answer, but I have errors with unit translations

Comment: I have defined my function, it is quadratic, but my coefficients are very different from yours: (a, b, c): [ 8.68054413e-04 -6.27895699e-01 3.47654611e+02] this is for the characteristics of the first diesel

Comment: @SigelAlex See edit. Consumption is linear and not quadratic.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best option, because this load can be provided by two diesels and with less fuel consumption. 3 and 4 diesel engines can handle this load

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Just look at the graph - diesel engines 3 and 4 have the _worst_ fuel consumption out of all of them.

Comment: With all engines available, the solution above produces total consumption of 232593. With your solution restricted to only engines 3 and 4, that consumption increases to 245558.

Comment: Thank you, you are simply the best, I am very grateful to you for your work!

Comment: Hello, we have come to the conclusion that gram consumption per hour is not suitable for us, and we can only operate with unit costs, as in the source data, how can we correct this in your program?

Comment: Outside of the scope of this question. Ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly easier to understand than building up a dynamic programming data structure is memoized recursion (which is top-down in nature):

```
from functools import cache
        
def combinations(matrix, target):
    @cache
    def combos(target, numcols):
        if numcols == 0:  
            if target == 0:  # base case success
                return [[]]
            return []  # base case failure
        col = numcols - 1
        result = []
        for row in matrix:
            val = row[col]
            for combo in combos(target-val, numcols-1):
                result.append(combo + [val])
        return result
    return combos(target, len(matrix[0]))

m = [
  [1,2,3],
  [2,3,1],
  [0,1,5],
]
 
combinations(m, 6)
# [[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [0, 1, 5]]
```

The worst case here is still pretty darn large (375^6), but any target number already seen with same number of columns left will be a cache hit. If you know e.g. that all numbers in the matrix are positive you can already short-circuit as soon as your target number is negative to further improve performance.